# Error when trying to import rpy2.robjects in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rstudio

I can import the rpy2 library without ant issue

```
import rpy2
```

However, when I want to import other objects from this package, I get errors

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector
```

For these imports, I get the following errors:

```
Unable to determine R home: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

R[write to console]: Error: cons memory exhausted (limit reached?)

R[write to console]: Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

I have installed Rstudio but aparrently, there is no connection between Rstudio and Microsoft Visual Code Studio, from which I run the Python code.